# Como saber o número de linhas que um arquivo grande possui em php?

Tags: php, arquivo

Como faço para saber o número de linhas existente em um arquivo usando PHP?

Sei que existem funções como `file`, que retorna todas as linhas do arquivo num `array`. Poderíamos simplesmente usar um `count`, mas o problema é que preciso fazer isso para um arquivo de `60mb`, e não acho uma boa ideia usar `file` nesse caso.

Tem alguma outra maneira de fazer isso?

Como posso saber, por exemplo, quantas linhas existem num arquivo de `2gb`, sem estourar a memória do PHP?

Existe alguma maneira mais inteligente de contar as linhas de um arquivo em PHP?

Comment: Da uma olhada na resposta da da pergunta [Efficiently Counting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162497/efficiently-counting-the-number-of-lines-of-a-text-file-200mb) no So-en.

Comment: @David aí você me quebra, tenho uma resposta em inglês lá, kkkkkkkk... Mas como quero ajudar a comunidade brasileira/portuguesa, pensei em colocar aqui também

Comment: @David não é errado fazer isso aqui, mas algumas pessoas acham que isso é má fé. Na verdade, tem muita coisa que já está no SOEN que está repetido aqui

Comment: Também acho certo ter repetido, pois quem entende inglês mais ou menos, pode não se atentar a algum detalhe da interpretação da resposta, sendo que aqui em português fica mais claro :)

Comment: Se tiver algum corajoso aí... pode dar uma olhadinha aqui: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/coreutils/src/wc.c. Até onde eu vi... o wc funciona pegando chunks e lendo caractere por caractere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem que lê-lo em *chunks* de dados. Mais ou menos assim:

```
$file = fopen("teste.txt",'r');
$count = 0;
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file, 4096); //provavelmente eu colocaria um valor maior, jamais menor
    $count++;
}
fclose($file);
```

Coloquei um limite de 4096 *bytes* porque corre risco se o arquivo for grande demais e não tiver quebras de linha suficientes para criar *chunks* pequenos. Esta solução não é perfeita. Uma melhor precisaria de um algoritmo bem mais sofisticado.

Eu cheguei pensar em uma outra que tem problemas também:

```
$file = fopen("teste.txt",'rb');
$count = 0;
while (!feof($file)) {
    $chunk= fread($f, 4096); //provavelmente eu colocaria um valor maior, jamais menor
    $count += substr_count($chunk, "\n");
}
fclose($file);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/IO/ReadChuncks.php).

A quebra de linha pode ter mais de um caractere e ficar um caractere em um *chunk* e o outro no próximo *chunk*. Aí não vai contar.

Soluções prontas para produção teriam que considerar isso e tratar quando acontecer. Isso é mais fácil de resolver no segundo algoritmo. Ele ainda tem a vantagem de nunca encher a memória.

Faça testes para avaliar o melhor tamanho do *chunk*. Coloquei 4K porque é o tamanho da página de memória e o tamanho mais comum do *cluster* do sistema de arquivos. Menores serão piores e tendem a ter mais risco de cortar linha pela metade atrapalhando os dois algoritmos. Maiores podem dar resultados bem melhores. Eu arriscaria dizer que quanto maior melhor, mas depende do hardware, SO, padrão de uso, etc. Ele pode ficar bom em teste e criar algum problema no uso em produção. Se pudesse ler o arquivo todo sempre seria o mais rápido e sem riscos.

O GuilhermeLautert levantou uma questão do `\n` ser só o *line feed* e portanto não causaria problema na quebra. Mas no Windows a quebra é `\r\n` (não tenho como testar). Das duas uma ou o PHP considera o `\n` no código como quebra de linha completa e acontece o que eu falei, ou este código não funcionaria corretamente no Windows, exigindo o uso do `\r\n` no código para pegar a quebra da forma correta, o que teria o problema de dividir o indicador de quebra de linha do mesmo jeito.

- [`stream-get-line()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php)
- [`fgets()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)
- [`fread()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)
- [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
- [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

Comment: Parecido com a que está no SOEN, kkkkkkk +1

Comment: Mas porque 4096? Não é só usar fgets?

Comment: Essas funções da stream está me deixando mais animado a mexer com a procedural no PHP

Comment: Essa sua segunda solução creio ser a ideal, pois reapreveita a memória nas `chunks`, só "A quebra de linha pode ter mais de um caractere e ficar um caractere em um chunck e o outro no próximo chunck. Aí não vai contar." Porque não contaria? Mesmo se tiver `\n\n` e cada em fica em uma `chunck` ele vai contar 1+1.

Comment: Um pequeno detalhe (eu também confundo isso): É "chunck" ou "chunk"?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert O problema é o que `\n` é abstrato. De fato um único `\n` pode ter concretamente um byte `CR` e depois um `LF`, somente eles juntos é a quebra de linha, separados, não é nada. Imagino eu que seja nada. Imagino que o algoritmo não os considere separadamente (no Windows por exemplo), se considerar, aí conta duas quebras quando na verdade é apenas uma.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters é, eu estava lendo e falando que tinha algo errado, mas não via o que :)

Comment: @bigown nesse caso a constante `PHP_EOL` não resolve (acho que ela muda de acordo com o SO)?

Comment: @bigown se você usar `fgets` sem o segundo parâmetro, ele vai ler a linha inteira. Isso já não é bom? Pois afinal de contas, se eu quero contar as linhas, o tamanho da mesma não interessa, certo?

Comment: Mas o `LF` é "retorno de carro", no windows ele só serve para fazer o ponteiro voltar ao inicio de linha, caso contrario ele apenas iria para baixo, e isso vai depender do software de leitura, pois alguns ao aplicar `CR` já dão `LF`. A quebra de linha mesmo é o `CR`(\n), o `LF`(\r) é só anexo.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não conheço o mecanismo exato do PHP, mas até onde eu sei o `\n` é justamemente o `PHP_EOL`, que muda de acordo com o SO. E se a linha tiver 2GB? Ou seja, se não tiver uma quebra? Se tiver algumas poucas e ficar grande demais, assim mesmo? Eu fiz um algoritmo que resolve seu problema. Ele, assim bruto, causa outro. Nada díficil de resolver, principalmente no segundo algoritmo. Só teria que verificar o último caractere do *chunk* e o primeiro do próximo. Se juntos formarem uma quebra de linha, conta, senão não conta. Se eu tiver saco depois eu faço. E vejo se é só isto mesmo :)

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Não estou tão certo quanto você que o PHP funciona assim. Precisaria testar. Se funcionar assim ainda seria um problema se a quebra de linha for o `\r\n` e tiver só o `\n` no texto sem ser uma quebra de linha efetivamente.

Answer (score 4):

Os dois métodos ( fgets() e file()) usam loop para ler o arquivo (o que é inevitável). Ou seja implicitamente ou explicitamente existirá um loop passando por todas as linhas do arquivo.

Mas vc só quer saber o número de linhas, então não importa o tamanho do arquivo pois vc só vai gravar um valor.
Faça isso:

```
$myfile = fopen("meuArquivo.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
while(!feof($myfile)) {
  $count++;
}
fclose($myfile);
echo $count;
```

Comment: Acho que tem um erro aí. Sem `fgets` ele vai entrar num loop infinito, já que não passa para a próxima linha

Comment: OI Wallace. Acho que não. Veja: fgets — Gets line from file pointer. (Ele não quer o conteúdo da linha e sim passar por ela. Ele só quer saber quantas linhas o arquivo tem) e while(!feof ... = Enquanto o fim do arquivo não for alcaçado, mova o ponteiro para a próxima linha. A condição do fim do loop é a negação do feof(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php    ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,  http://php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php

Answer (score 2):

Eu, como amante do OOP em PHP, faria isso com o objeto `SplFileObject`

```
$file = new \SplFileObject('file.extension', 'r');
$file->seek(PHP_INT_MAX);
echo $file->key() + 1;
```

Eu utilizo o `PHP_INT_MAX` para apontar para a última linha do arquivo, pois `SplFileObject` implementa `SeekableIterator`.

Daí, como a contagem das linhas começa por `0`, eu tenho que somar `+1` para trazer o valor certo.

Outra detalhe: Como estou usando `SplFileObject`, a iteração de um arquivo grande seria feita linha por linha, economizando assim na memória e podendo se contar um arquivo gigante, sem travar o script.

Comment: Essa deveria ser a resposta marcada como aceita. Usando a outra resposta, também poderia fazer: `while (($line = fgets($file, 8192)) !== false) { $count++; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Como amante de REGEX proponho:

```
$content = file_get_contents("file_name");          //  LE TODO ARQUIVO
$content = preg_replace('~[^\n]~', '', $content);   //  REMOVE TUDO QUE NÃO SEJA QUEBRA DE LINHA (\n)
print_r(strlen($content)+1);                        //  CONTA QUANTOS BYTES SOBRARAM, +1 POIS NO FINAL DO ARQUIVO NÃO TEM \n
```

Comment: Cara, é interessante essa técnica, faz sentido. Minha preocupação é com os arquivos de `2 gb` , que no caso travaria até o PC se tenta-se rodar no PHP.

Comment: Te imitei... O "Amante do OOP"