# Como saber o número de linhas que um arquivo grande possui em C#?

Tags: c#

Bem, estou começando agora em C#, porém já tenho uma grande experiência com PHP e sei mais ou menos `Python`.

E os meios que costumo utilizar para apender é fazer algo que achei difícil fazer numa linguagem que eu sei em uma linguagem que eu não sei nada.

Eu perguntei aqui como contar as linhas de um arquivo grande em PHP, pois é algo que não é tão simples de fazer na linguagem, não tem uma função específica para isso, tenho que fazer manobras.

Agora que eu estou aprendendo `C#`, eu gostaria de saber como faço para saber quantas linhas tem um arquivo grande.

Mas gostaria que cada função usada fosse explicada, porque não entendo muito de C# ainda.

Quero ler um `JSON` de `6.6MB` aqui da minha máquina e saber quantas linhas ele têm através do C#.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A classe `File` (`System.IO.File`), tem um método [`ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx).

Ele faz um carregamento preguiçoso das linhas do arquivo, isto é, determinada linha só será carregada para a memória quando for solicitado.

Então, você pode fazer:

```
var qtdLinhas = File.ReadLines("C:\\Users\\Wallace\\arquivo.json").Count();
```

Comment: Bem, está melhor [que o PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128387/como-saber-o-n%c3%bamero-de-linhas-que-um-arquivo-grande-possui-em-php/128397#128389) então +1

Comment: Só acho importante lembrar que o `Count` força a leitura do arquivo inteiro, o que não fica muito claro no código, mas basicamente a única forma de se saber quantas linhas um arquivo tem é ir lendo e contando quantas linhas existem nele.

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa desde que essa leitura não carregue todas as linhas para a memória, não há problema. O objetivo realmente é ler um arquivo grande, creio que a resposta atenda

Comment: Se o seu objetivo é ler o arquivo inteiro, fazer essa contagem "antes" é bobagem porque vc vai acabar lendo o arquivo duas vezes. Qual é o objetivo de saber o número de linhas? Seria pra utilizar numa barra de progresso (isto é, estimando o percentual concluido)? Se for, eu sugeriria "estimar" o número de linhas com base no tamanho do arquivo (assume uma média de 80 caracteres por linha, por exemplo). Ou, mais precisamente, usar o número de caracteres lidos. :)

Comment: Na verdade a pergunta não se aplica a um contexto específico @LuizVieira. Era uma dúvida do AP.

Comment: Desculpe, eu acabei postando na sua resposta sem querer. Mas o meu comentário é justamente pro AP.  :)

Comment: Eu tinha percebido :P

Answer (score 5):

Mais manualmente, você também poderia usar esse algoritmo (Também trabalhando com o System.IO)...

No Stream o Peek retorna o próximo caractere, sem avançar o ponteiro do Stream... e caso não haja mais caracteres ele retorna -1, portanto aproveitei ele para usar no while... pelo menos em meus testes (não tenho nenhum arquivo de 6mb) o meu algoritmo levou meio milésimo para ler um arquivo de texto com 103kb... quanto o File.ReadLine levou 22 milésimos...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

bem, ambos algoritmos funcionam bem, com ótimo desempenho, cabe você a escolher...

```
string filename = "c:\input.txt"
TextReader Leitor = new StreamReader(filename, true);//Inicializa o Leitor
int Linhas = 0;
while (Leitor.Peek() != -1) {//Enquanto o arquivo não acabar, o Peek não retorna -1 sendo adequando para o loop while...
    Linhas++;//Incrementa 1 na contagem
    Leitor.ReadLine();//Avança uma linha no arquivo
}
Leitor.Close(); //Fecha o Leitor, dando acesso ao arquivo para outros programas....
Console.WriteLine("Este Arquivo contém " + Linhas + " Linhas.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Realmente o tempo é bem parelho **+1**