# Como funciona a lógica para se descobrir o tamanho da imagem?

Tags: arquivo, imagem, processamento-de-imagens

No PHP e em outras linguagens de programação, é possível, através de algumas funções especiais, descobrir o tamanho da imagem.

Por exemplo:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('images/icon.png');
```

Eu fiquei curioso em saber como é que as linguagens fazem isso. De onde é que vem a informação que a imagem tem aquele tamanho?

Eu queria entender como é feita a leitura dessas informações.

A minha dúvida surgiu pois quando fiz essa pergunta [Como saber o número de linhas que um arquivo grande possui em php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128387/como-saber-o-n%C3%BAmero-de-linhas-que-um-arquivo-grande-possui-em-php), eu percebia que, nos meus testes, os arquivos grandes demoravam muito para serem processados.

Porém quando fiz o  teste com imagens grandes e pequenas, para saber o tamanho das mesmas, o tempo de respostas foram os mesmos. Então, aparentemente, a função responsável por capturar essas informações não leu o arquivo todo, mas retornou essa informação de algum lugar.

E o que eu queria saber é  de onde vem essas informações?

Como é possível saber, por exemplo, o *mime* de uma imagem, com tanta agilidade? Digo "agilidade", pois mesmo que uma imagem tivesse 20MB, a velocidade de leitura dessas informações sempre são os mesmos.

Onde fica guardada essa "informação"? Como é feito o processamento do tamanho da imagem?

Comment: A chave para entender está contida nos metadados. A resposta para a pergunta não é complexa mas para ser completa é longa...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Obviamente o arquivo possui metadados com as informações relevantes. Normalmente é um cabeçalho com os dados, seu formato varia em cada tipo de imagem de acordo com alguma especificação normalmente pública para que todos possam desenvolver seus algoritmos para pegar/manipular as informações que deseje.

Além dos dados básicos que formam a imagem propriamente dita é comum o arquivo começar com uma "assinatura" para que ele possa ser facilmente reconhecido como sendo daquele formato. É comum ter um versionamento nessa assinatura.

Diversas bibliotecas existentes já fazem o que você deseja e estão disponíveis para várias linguagens, como é o caso do PHP. A linguagem não faz nada, mas sim esse código que até pode fazer parte da biblioteca padrão. Quem a fez certamente estudou a especificação e criou o código necessário. No fundo é só ler alguns bytes em posições específicas do arquivo.

O algoritmo provavelmente analisa se os dados estão bem formados. Alguns formatos podem ajudar esse tipo de verificação (com [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check), por exemplo), outros são mais suscetíveis à corrupção. E confirmando o comentário abaixo: sim, é chato fazer certo, por isso que você vê as pessoas usando coisas prontas.

Na verdade a técnica é válida para qualquer tipo de arquivo, não só imagem. Sempre que precisar recuperar uma informação em [complexidade O(1)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/101), e ela pode ser obtida previamente, guarde ela em algum lugar, preferencialmente logo no começo e em posição fixa para garantir o O(1) "firme".

Tentar descobrir a informação por conta própria terá provável complexidade O(N) que é bem pior, ainda que não trágica.

No caso do PNG há um *chunk* chamado IHDR começando com a sequência de bytes `73 72 68 82` e depois a seguinte estrutura com os dados que se refere a pergunta:

```
Width               4 bytes //tamanho aqui
Height              4 bytes //tamanho aqui
Bit depth           1 byte
Colour type         1 byte
Compression method  1 byte
Filter method       1 byte
Interlace method    1 byte
```

- [Especificação do PNG](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11IHDR) ([completa](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/PNG/) e [resumo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Technical_details)).
- [Especificação do JPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure) ([informação extra](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/)).
- [Especificação do GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#File_format) ([completa](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt)).
- [Especificação e informações do SVG](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/)

Há um [site com formatos de arquivos](http://www.fileformat.info/). Não sei se é bom.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Se o link não apontasse para onde aponta diria que é relevante para a resposta detalhar.

Comment: Conheço o bigown @MagicHat, ele vai editar a resposta um monte de vezes para adicionar mais informações :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Nice... É uma ótima pergunta, até onde eu o conheço, certamente vai responder a altura.

Comment: Ótima resposta. É isso mesmo, arquivos de imagem têm a informação num cabeçalho. Concordo com o @MagicHat, acho que vale a pena colocar um exemplo da parte relevante do cabeçalho do PNG no corpo da pergunta. :)

Comment: E, quem sabe, também os links de outras especificações, como o [JPG](http://www.fastgraph.com/help/jpeg_header_format.html), [GIF](http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/gif.html#header) e [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header) (o mais zoneado :p ).

Comment: Que paranauê para descobrir essas informações, hein

Comment: Posso melhora mais, pode sugerir

Comment: Bom @bigown pelo perfil de suas respostas, sugiro dar uma incrementada abordando um pouco sobre o ""exif", através do PHP, ou para os fãs de Windows o GDI, ou os 2, minha sugestão.