# O que são metadados em relação a documentos HTML?

Tags: html, característica-linguagem

Estou lendo um [livro](http://www.w3c.br/pub/Cursos/CursoHTML5/html5-web.pdf) sobre HTML.

Na pagina 19 é citado as **Categorias**.

> Cada elemento no HTML pode ou não fazer parte de um grupo de elementos
> com características similares.

E em seguida é listada as categorias desses grupos:

- Metadata content
- Flow content

e mais algumas categorias...

A minha dúvida está na categoria *Metadata content*, que me parece ser algum tipo de metadados de uma pagina HTML.

---

## Dúvidas

1. Eu não sei o que siginifica metadados. E eu gostaria de saber o que é
   metadados em relação a documentos HTML?
2. Qual é a importancia desses metadados para um documento
   HTML (paginas web)?

Comment: Relacionado: [O que são metadados?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107111/o-que-s%C3%A3o-metadados)

Comment: Relacionado (porque fala de metadados): [Como funciona a lógica pra se obter o tamanho de uma imagem?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136496/como-funciona-a-l%C3%B3gica-para-se-descobrir-o-tamanho-da-imagem)

Comment: Algumas coisas que podem lhe interessar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/454947/3635

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De forma simples, metadados, são dados que fornecem informação sobre outros dados, ou dados sobre dados como diz o [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata). Se você entende de programação pode facilmente associar isso ao conceito de `arrays` com `indices` semânticos.

Por exemplo numa imagem, um dado referente a essa imagem (*tamanho, etc*), pode ser usado para criar a informação também referente à essa imagem, através disso qualquer entidade consegue saber que a imagem x possui y de tamanho.

Numa página web, ou num documento `HTML` que em princípio tem como principal objectivo a construção do esqueleto do website, a ideia é a mesma, enunciar como a página está organizada, dizendo onde estão os cabeçalhos, os títulos, o conteúdo e por aí, usando palavras chaves específicas para cada área do documento. Num documento do word, ou qualquer outro processador de textos faz quase a mesma coisa, senão na totalidade - *XML*.

Outro exemplo poderiam ser as `tags` que você usou ao criar essa pergunta:

> html e característica-linguagem

Eu, mesmo antes de visualizar a pergunta, pude saber que está relacionada com `html`, e ao ver o conteúdo da pergunta, vi *"palavras"* em negrito, com fonte maior que ao restante da página, e pude saber que era o título, e ao ver o texto com fonte regular situado abaixo do título soube também que era o conteúdo, no final, ao ler, pude comprovar que está realmente relacionada com `html`.

Se as `tags` estivessem erradas, ainda que eu lesse o conteúdo *(que aborda sobre C)*, eu ficaria confuso, porque, imagina: *vim cá à espera de encontrar conteúdo sobre html, mas encontrei algo diferente, como lido com isso ?*. Pior seria se a pergunta não tivesse qualquer `tag`, eu claramente conseguiria perceber que se trata de `HTML` pelo que está vinculado ao título, e por a pergunta estar na página principal do site, mas alguém navegando pelas *tags* `HTML` teria sequer encontrado a pergunta ?

Apesar de exemplo com pessoas, quando se fala *metatags* refere-se ao mundo digital.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Eu não sei o que siginifica metadados. E eu gostaria de saber o que
>      é metadados em relação a documentos HTML?

Como já foi explicado o que são os metadados, vou explicar para que servem em documentos HTML.

Os documentos HTML podem servir para vários propósitos diferentes, sendo praticamente tudo que você visualiza na web, montado com HTML.

Os metadados ficam no cabeçalho de uma página HTML e são as primeiras informações lidas à respeito do documento. Podendo trazer informações como *título da página* (**title**), *versão da linguagem de marcação* (**!DOCTYPE**), *autor do documento* (**meta name="author"**) etc.

> 2. Qual é a importancia desses metadados para um documento HTML
>      (paginas web)?

Eles são muito importantes, pois o navegador e as ferramentas de busca utilizam dessas informações constantemente para melhorar a experiência do usuário, trazendo respostas de busca mais concisas e diferenciando as abas do navegador por títulos e *favicons* diferentes que representam seu site.

Answer (score 0):

> Eu não sei o que siginifica metadados. E eu gostaria de saber o que
>   é metadados em relação a documentos HTML?

De forma bem breve, os metadados são utilizado para expor informações relevante do seu site de forma publica e com tag com nome padrão para cada informação, por exemplo, caso queria expor quem é o desenvolvedor ou equipe que criou o site, utilize essa tag:

```
<meta name="author" content="Edvaldo Farias" />
```

> Qual é a importancia desses metadados para um documento HTML
>   (paginas web)?

Ele é muito importante para diversos serviços, mas o motivo principal hoje em dia é referente ao motores de buscar de site como Google, bing e etc. Os metadados ajudam a identificar informações importante de forma fácil, rápida e padronizada.

Comment: sabia que tem vários tipos de metadados ?

Comment: Sim, mas acredito que ele esteja falando desse especifico <meta>. Caso não seja, interpretei errado.